# Responsive map made of multiple image files

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm pretty much a total noob when it comes to responsive web design and I'm attempting to produce a responsive web app with an interactive map.

The map is made up of seven separate image files - one for each region. The map has to be split in to separate images so that I can change the transparency of each image (and therefore, the regions color intensity) depending on data taken from the database.

I want the map to be centered but I also want each region's individual image (that makes up the map) to retain its position.

The best analogy I can think of is a jigsaw where the pieces maintain their correct position to complete the jigsaw's image even when the browser is resized.

What is the easiest way for this to be achieved?

Bare in mind that I still need to be able to control the transparency of each regions image.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I do not know where to start! Sorry if my description is poor - feel free to probe.

Cheers,

Will

Comment: Are you using any libraries to generate the map (e.g., some mapping plugin) or is this "map" in the general sense?

Comment: This is a map in the general sense - sorry for my poor description. It is a graphic that I produced in Photoshop that represents a world map. I exported the graphic as multiple PNGs (one for each region) so that I could control the opacity of each region's graphic. I hope that makes sense. I feel like I'm over complicating my description.

Comment: I think your best bet is going to be using SVGs. Any experience there?

Comment: Store these maps pieces in a table and use media screen @ to do the responsive design. Should be easy enough.

Comment: @jonmrich I have no experience with SVGs. I shall investigate. If you have any links to resources relating to them that would be very helpful! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Forgive me for my naivety, what do you mean by 'media screen @', @anson920520?

Comment: This is the most important function when you develop a responsive site: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @jonmrich I just did a quick Google and I think you are right - SVGs are the solution! Case closed for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's a good resource that will get you started: http://demosthenes.info/blog/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps

Comment: @anson920520 Ah, apologies. Up until now I've been building from a CSS template. All good experience! I'll give it a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an SVG made in illustrator which worked perfectly. Embedded it inline as apposed to having an SVG file in the directory.